# Setting focus to input element on validation error not working

Tags: javascript, php

I have a long list of input fields created from data in a database, more or less like this:

```
foreach ($data as $value) { 
...

<input type="text" name="date_earned$row" id="date_earned$row" value = "$date_earned" onchange="changeDate(this)">
...
}
```

The onchange script is like this (note: the date is not a standard date so I'm not trying to validate a normal date).  It won't let me set focus back to the element that I just changed, if there is an error.  I have no trouble setting the focus to a different element.  Why?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeDate(sel) {
  var theDate = sel.value;
  var isValid = true;
  if (theDate) {
 <!-- .... some stuff in here to validate the date, sets isValid = false if it is not correct format} -->
}

 if (!(isValid)) {
<!--    ... do some stuff in here to display the error message -->
  document.getElementById('thiselementsid').focus(); <!-- this doesn't work when 'thiselementsid' is the id of the element which just lost focus-->
  document.getElementById('someotherelement').focus(); <!-- this works, but not if 'someotherelement' is the id of the last focused element -->
```

}

Comment: Try wrapping your commands in a setTimeout to send them down the stack like so `setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('thiselementsid').focus()}, 0);`. I think that when focus shifts, it fires the event before moving the focus off, so setting the focus again on the same element won't work.

Comment: Cool. You should accept Steven's answer then because he made the same suggestion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing that strikes me is that you are missing an apostrophe in the line

```
document.getElementById('thiselementsid).focus();
```

after "thiselementsid."  I don't know if that's the source of your problem or if it's just example code.

It's also possible that some subsequent code is calling something along the lines of `document.getElementById('thiselementsid').blur()` (blur is the order to lose focus).  Evan's suggestion in a comment appended to your question would solve that - `setTimeout` would delay the setting of focus until after the blur() method was called.

There are other possibilities, most of them rather nasty.  Let us know in an edit if you're still having problems.  It might be good in that case to provide more of the surrounding code.

Comment: That's just a typo, it's there in the real script

Answer (score -2):

You can set it like this as well.

```
document.getElementById('thiselementsid').focus() = true;
```

Comment: I suspect this would throw an error similar to this: *"Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment"*